# AJAX form checkbox array value gets "stuck" hanging

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, checkbox

To make it really short and simple.

I have an AJAX form with method="GET", because I want to reflect all the changes in the URL (and for it to be accessible afterwards).
And the form is getting submitted to the server automatically when either of form elements is changed. On the server I rewrite the URL by using "history pushState".

I'm using Ruby-on-Rails as a server-side technology, if it matters.

One of the elements checkbox array (multiple elements can be chosen) - it is a list of parameters that user would like to see.

Now to the problem itself - suppose we visit this page for the first time. 
None of checkboxes is checked so far. Then we check, for example, first checkbox. 
Event is triggered - form is getting submitted -> url is rewritten properly.
Then I uncheck this checkbox -> event is triggered -> form gets submitted -> url is rewritten properly again!

Everything is correct so far.

And now the case that does NOT work. 
I check this checkbox -> form is submitted -> url rewritten. Correct. And after that I hit "refresh" (F5 or Ctrl-R). I see that the checkbox is checked (as it is supposed to be), but ... I attempt to UNCHECK this checkbox, BUT for some odd reason on the server-side I still see this array value reaching the server. And, of course, it is reflected in the URL as well - it is present there (while it should not).

Sorry for messy explanation.

I'm I doing something extremely wrong?

P.S Form works correctly with ordinary parameters (fields, mainly).

P.P.S I was really curious - what is going on there, and I even attempted to see form values before they got submitted to the server by executing following code:

```
$("#my-form").on("ajax:beforeSend", function(){
    console.log("FORM BEFORE SUBMISSION: " + $(this).serialize());
});
```

And the checkbox is absent there. Which is correct!

Thanks in advance!

P.P.P.S This is how my idea is implemented in general (very briefly):

```
<form method="GET" action="/search/?" id="my-form" data-remote="true">
... (some form elements here as well)
<input type="checkbox" name="search[types][]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="search[types][]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="search[types][]" value="3">
... (and submit button)
</form>

$("#my-form").change(function(){ $(this).submit(); });
```

Comment: The problem with answering this is you've isolated what you think is the problem and shown only that line. Please show the relevant HTML and javascript.

Comment: The code is on my work office machine - I would be able to show the code tomorrow the earliest in that case.

Updated the question with the code.

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Comment: `$("#my-form").change(function(){ $(this).submit(); });` actually triggers? `$("#my-form checkbox").change(function(){ $(this).submit(); });` makes more sense to me.

Comment: Trigger works flawlessly. You should take into account that checkboxes are not the only elements there is in the form! There are also input fields, buttons, etc.

Comment: is checkbox an html component?

Comment: Yep. <input type="checkbox" ... >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone for wasting your precious time.

I found the problem - I used query-params as form "action" attribute, so submitting the form caused query params duplication every single time I refreshed the page before submitting it.

Easy :) Should have thought about it in the first place.